# Enqueue scripts all over but not in single.php

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

I need to insert this script in the footer on the home, in categories, in pages, in the tags in the search but NOT in `single.php`:

```
function live_search() {
    wp_enqueue_script('live_search', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') .'/assets/js/live.search.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.1', true );
    wp_localize_script( 
        'live_search', 
        'MovieWordpressSearch', 
        array( 
            'api' => moviewp_url_search(),
            'nonce' => moviewp_create_nonce('moviewp-search-nonce'),
            'area' => ".live-search",
            'more' => "Show all",
            ) 
        );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'live_search');
```

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a perfect situation for [Conditional Tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/)

Comment: Note that if a theme was built properly, the body tag will have HTML classes that can be used to identify single pages, allowing you to detect it in JS and avoid running code

Comment: To add to what Tom J Nowell said, I’ve now made it a rule to always first check the length of the container item (if it exists) before executing any script code. That allows me to minimize the number of scripts I load for themes and plugins.  A simple if( $(‘#parent_container’).length > 0 ) { //do something } ensures I only run functions on pages where they should be run.

Answer (score 0):

with is_singular()

```
if (!is_singular('post')) {
    function live_search() {
        wp_enqueue_script('live_search', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') .'/assets/js/live.search.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.1', true );
        wp_localize_script( 
            'live_search', 
            'MovieWordpressSearch', 
            array( 
                'api' => moviewp_url_search(),
                'nonce' => moviewp_create_nonce('moviewp-search-nonce'),
                'area' => ".live-search",
                'more' => "Show all",
                ) 
            );
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'live_search');
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work as it's too early in the load process to use `is_single` or `is_singular`, or any of the conditional functions that rely on the loop/main query. By the time those functions are available that hook has already fired and it's too late

Comment: is singular is just what I don't want, I want the script to be everywhere but not in the single.php file